# swift how to convert special unicode

Tags: swift, unicode

```
let result = ["response": response,
              "callbackId": callbackId]

do {
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(result, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    var str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String

    str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
    str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "\\\"")
    str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "\\\'")
    str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\\n")
    str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: "\\r")
    //                            str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\f", withString: "\\f")
    //                            str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u2028", withString: "\\u2028")
    //            str = str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u2029", withString: "\\u2029")

    return "bridge.invokeJs('{\"response\" : {\"username\" : \"zhongan\"},\"callbackId\" : \(callbackId)}')"
} catch {
    return nil
}
```

I want to convert the json string to js script, and then call `evaluateJavaScript`, but can not convert the special character, like `\f` `\u2029`, this will give a compiler error and I don't know why.

Comment: Your dance with backslash characters tells me that you have an ecoding issue with your source to begin with, and that you should fix it before going further.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) Section *Special Characters in String Literals*.

According to this page `\f` is not defined.

> - The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t
>     (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double
>     quote) and \' (single quote)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as
>     \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to
>     a valid Unicode code point

So

- `\f` Form Feed you may be written in escaped form as `\u{000C}`
- `\u2029` Page Feed has to be escaped as `\u{2029}`
- `\u2028` Line Separator has to be escaped as `\u{2028}`

See also "[Unicode Control Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters)"